# deleting rows from csv based on cell contents from another csv

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

i am crawling a list of urls from a csv and pulling the dataframe info from each url and exporting it to a csv. it stops when it hits a page that doesn't have any info.  i'm wanting to delete the urls from the first file (they contain the license number) that i have already crawled based on license numbers i have collected from the second file.  i can do this easily in excel by using a helper column, but have no clue how to do it with pandas.

for example: 
i want to delete the first 2 rows(urls) in file1 based on the Lic # in file2.

```
File1(no headers)
www.1234.com
www.1235.com
www.1236.com

File2(LIC# is the header)
1234
1235

new urls (expected output back into File1)
www.1236
```

I've looked over many examples on here and am having trouble wrapping my head around it.

I appreciate any comments and/or suggestions.

Comment: can you show toy examples of datasets & expected output?

Comment: i provided them in the initial question, but updated the wording to reflect what you're asking for.  I believe.

Answer (score 1):

Storing your 2 lists in x and a variables:

```
x=['www.1234.com','www.1235.com','www.1236.com']
a=['1234','1235']
```

Appending www. and .com to your second list and storing in a variable b

```
b=[]
for i in a:
    b.append('www.'+i+'.com')
```

Creating your desired output

```
y = [s for s in x if s not in b]
y
```

Comment: If the answer helped you please accept and upvote. Thanks :)

Comment: i just updated the initial question to clarify what had column names and what the expected output.  I apologize for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

First, create a new column which contain only middle part of url

```
df1['site'] = dfs['dataset1'].apply(lambda x:x.split('.')[1])
```

Then, inner join both the dataframes

```
df = df1.merge(df2,how='inner',left_on='site',right_on='dataset2')
```

The df contains the required output.
(I am assuming dataset1 and dataset2 are the column names)

Comment: i just updated the initial question to clarify what had column names and what the expected output.  I apologize for any confusion.

Answer (score 0):

if both are different dataframes of large size , you may use join or you can check by iterating 
df

```
df
    File1(no headers)
0   www.1234.com
1   www.1235.com
2   www.1236.com

df1
    File2(LIC# is the header)
0   1234
1   1235

df = df[~df['File1(no headers)'].apply(lambda y: any(map(lambda x :str(x) in y,df1['File2(LIC# is the header)'].tolist())))].reset_index(drop=True)
```

Out:

```
    File1(no headers)
0   www.1236.com
```

Comment: i just updated the initial question to clarify what had column names and what the expected output.  I apologize for any confusion.

Comment: i just edited my response to fit on yoiur column names@RobK